# xhtml2pdf does not detect div width

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I am using xhtml2pdf for converting html to pdf.

For some reason it does not detect the width of any div. I have tried giving width using style  it still does not work. What am I do doing wrong?

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<style>
    div{
        width:100pt;
        height:100pt;
        border:Solid red 1pt;
    }
</style>
<div>
    WOw a pdf
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code the div does not have a width of 100px or 100pt.

```
def myview(request):
    options1 = ReportPropertyOption.objects.all()
    for option in options1:
        option.exterior_images = ReportExteriorImages.objects.filter(report = option)  
        option.interior_images = ReportInteriorImages.objects.filter(report = option)
        option.floorplan_images = ReportFloorPlanImages.objects.filter(report = option)

    html  = render_to_string('report/export.html', { 'pagesize' : 'A4', }, context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'options1':options1}))
    result = StringIO.StringIO()

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources )
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('Gremlins ate your pdf! %s' % cgi.escape(html))

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):  

    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace("/media/", ""))

    return path.replace("\\","/")
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue; did you ever find a work around?

Comment: No I have not. But it detects table column width and I have used table everywhere instead of div.

Comment: What about height? Can't apply height to any element

Comment: You can explicitly add height and width to every element. You have add it specifically to each element.

Comment: What do you mean adding width and height specifically to each element? How can I do so?

Comment: Specifically means inline.